# Javascript: keep object 'this' scope within an event handler

Tags: javascript, object, xmlhttprequest

I have a `Stream` object taking care of an XML request:

```
/**
 * Init stream class.
 *
 * @param array actions
 * @param object options
 * @return void
 */
var Stream = function(actions, options)
{
    this.actions = !actions ? [] : actions;
    this.options = options;
}

/**
 * Stream completion handler.
 *
 * @param object evt
 * @return void
 */
Stream.prototype.complete = function(evt)
{
    console.log(this);
    // this is not the Stream object we're within,
    // instead it's the XMLHttpRequest object :(
}

/**
 * Start flowing the stream!
 *
 * @param void
 * @return void
 */
Stream.prototype.flow = function()
{
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.addEventListener('load', this.complete);
    req.open('GET', '/stream.php');
    req.send();   
}

new Stream([], {}).flow();
```

Problem is, on the `load` event listener - when I try to console log `this` (wanting to refer to `Stream`) - I get the `XMLHttpRequest` object instead. How do I go about retrieving my scope?

As you can tell, Vanilla JS is not my forte, but I've decided to work on it ;)

Guidance appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code to modify `.complete()` using [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind):

```
req.addEventListener('load', this.complete.bind(this));
```

When the request object uses your `this.complete` function, it invokes it with the context of the request object (`XMLHttpRequest` instance).
`this.complete.bind(this)` makes a new bound function that makes sure to have `this` an instance of `Stream`.

You can check more about this problem in [the following article](http://rainsoft.io/gentle-explanation-of-this-in-javascript/#32pitfallseparatingmethodfromitsobject).

Comment: Gawjus solution. Any idea on the browser support using this technique?

Comment: @Capio `.bind()` is supported well. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind#Browser_compatibility) to compatibility tables.

Answer (score 0):

add `var that = this;` before registering event and in event handler use `console.log(that);`

Comment: ...a better supported solution, although not what I'm going to go for, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

One other way could be;

```
req.addEventListener('load', function(e){e.target.complete()});
```